# How to update/flush dns cache on clients?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, domain-name-system, centos

When I have made changes on the DNS host.

How do I get the clients (servers) to update/flush their DNS cache, so they see the change right away?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can restart BIND on Ubuntu using `sudo rndc reload`, on Centos I believe you have to `/etc/init.d/bind restart`.

You can also execute `/etc/init.d/networking restart` to flush the DNS/networking for local desktops running Ubuntu.

Comment: I don't have references handy, but are you sure `rndc reload` clears the cache? I don't think it does.

Comment: If you make a change to the bind configurations, then it's better to flush the dns server using `rndc`, than restarting the service. If you change the hosts file, then flushing this is done via `/etc/init.d/networking restart`. I often find myself flushing these configurations.

Comment: None if these methods work on my debian wheezy box :( Also tried installing `nscd` and `bind9` just for flushing through those, didn't work.

Comment: `/etc/init.d/networking restart` crashes my Ubuntu desktop (GNOME Fallback, I think)

Answer (score 7):

I have found that a simple restart does not always clear the cache.
The other way of doing it, would be to use the nscd command and invalidate the hosts cache.

```
# nscd -i hosts
```

Then you don't even need to restart the caching service.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on you distribution, the clients may not cache by default.  For Ubuntu or CentOS, try this command:
sudo /etc/init.d/nscd status

...to see if the caching demon is running.  If it is, then your client is caching DNS and you can flush it with this:
sudo /etc/init.d/nscd restart

if NSCD is not running then there is nothing to flush on the client and you need to:
1. make sure the old entry is not in the /etc/hosts file
2. make sure the DNS change has already propagated to any DNS slaves (check the resolv.conf for where it is resolving to)